# How to pass powershell command in python script - Linux OS

Tags: python, linux, powershell, command

```
import datetime
from subprocess import PIPE

def abccompanycloudcmdrun(abccompanycloudcmd):
    abccompanycloudcmdrun_output = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", abccompanycloudcmd], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
    return abccompanycloudcmdrun_output

if __name__ == '__main__':

    abccompanycloudcmd_success = r"abccompanycloudcmd_success_" + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".log"
    abccompanycloudcmd_error = r"abccompanycloudcmd_error_" + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".log"

    abccompanycloudcmd = r**'Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $((Get-ADDomainController -DomainName abccompanycloud.com -Discover).hostname) ` | ft ComputerObjectDN'**
    abccompanycloudcmdrun_output = abccompanycloudcmdrun(abccompanycloudcmd)

    if abccompanycloudcmdrun_output.returncode != 0:
        print("abccompanycloudcmdrun - An error occured: %s", abccompanycloudcmdrun_output.stderr.decode("utf-8"), file = open(abccompanycloudcmd_error, 'a', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
    else:
        print("abccompanycloudcmdrun generated successfully!", file = open(abccompanycloudcmd_success, 'a', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
        print(abccompanycloudcmdrun_output.stdout.decode("utf-8"), file = open(abccompanycloudcmd_success, 'a', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

The above works fine without generating any errors in Windows. But doesnt work in Linux. It throws a message :  An error occured: %s b'-Command: powershell: command not found\n'

Question is How to pass the below powershell command in python script?
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $((Get-ADDomainController -DomainName abccompanycloud.com -Discover).hostname) ` | ft ComputerObjectDN

Comment: Running a list of tokens with `shell=True` is basically never correct. (Okay, there are scenarios where you can do it if you know what you are doing, but in the vast majority of cases, you don't want to even if you know how.) Remove the `shell=True` and you'll be fine.

Comment: No even after removing shell=True it doesnt work as expected.
bcgcloudcmdrun_output = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", bcgcloudcmd], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'powershell': 'powershell'

Comment: Well if you don't have `powershell` in your `PATH`, of course it will not find it. That's a separate problem.

Comment: I tried multiple ways , but none helped. How can I find the powershell path on AWS Server?

Comment: Did you install it in the first place? How? It's not a standard command on Linux so perhaps the real error is expecting it to be there.